# When using Tribe Events Calendar, querying for a specific event category returns nothing

Tags: posts, events, calendar

I'm still new to wordpress and I'm trying to write a plugin but for some reason this code is producing nothing. Why? I am completely stumped. I have followed the examples [here](http://tri.be/support/documentation/the-events-calendar-template-tags-general-functions/#functiontribe_get_events) to a tee.

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Text
    */

    add_action("init", "init_stuff");

    function x_get_event_posts(){
        $all_events = tribe_get_events(
            array(
                'eventDisplay' => 'all',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query'=> array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'xmlworkshopdonotuse'
                        )
                )
            )
        );

        echo count($all_events); // produces "0";
    }

    function init_stuff() {
        x_get_event_posts();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Are there actually published events in the `xmlworkshopdonotuse` category?

Comment: yes, 77 to be exact. actually any query using `tax_query` returns 0 results. Also, interestingly, `get_terms` returns a `WPError`.

Comment: That *is* odd, in light of the Codex's page on [`get_terms()`] saying that it will return `false` or a row from the DB.  How are you calling `get_terms()` that it's returning a `WP_Error`?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it turned out to be that I was using the incorrect action name. I changed `"init"` to `"wp_loaded"` in `add_action()` and that did the trick.

Comment: Great... any chance you can mark your answer as correct so we can close out this question?

Comment: Just a note to anyone who may find this still doesn't work - the code in the original post does work BUT it will only show upcoming (future) events.